# Is using timestamp as primary key good idea - mysql/mariadb?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, mariadb

We just argued that storing timestamp in sqlserver in microsoft does guarantee uniqueness, but im a little bit doubful about mysql/mariadb, because we are using parallel execution when inserting to the mysql/mariadb database.

So, Is using timestamp as primary key good idea - mysql/mariadb?

**PS: There is always an PK and status but its important if we are using timestamp as the where clause in getting the actual remaining records to be archived/removed (so that it is efficient in querying the records).So its important its unique**

Comment: Please provide the reference about SQL Server.  I am very dubious.

Comment: I would not trust even microsecond-resolution to be unique. Might work on a single machine today, but what about tomorrow's machine(s), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO it's bad because of several reasons. First, blindly assigning a generated p.k. for every relation is bad practice. At least try to identify what candidate keys there are in each relation. A surregate p.k. may be the smartest choice in some situations, but it is definitely not so in all possible situations. Good properties for candidate keys are:

- Unique
- Irreducible
- Non-complex
- Stable
- Familiar

Often there is a conflict between these criteria and you have to sacrifice one for another.

Second, if the best choice is a surrogate identifier I'll say that timestamp is a poor choice. Especially in MySQL/MariaDB before (MySQL) 5.6.4 where the resolution is seconds. Using a timestamp as a p.k in these DBMS means that you cannot insert more than one row / second (as long as the timestamp should reflect the time of insert).

Comment: are you considering the timestamp data type in mysql/mariadb right? timestamp is a poor choice is also my answer too thanks for enlightening me,

Comment: Yes, it was the timestamp I had in mind. In MySQL/MariaDB timestamp is not the same type as in other DBMS:s, it deviates from the standard in several aspects. Choosing another datetime type does not help either since the maximum resolution is second there as well.

Comment: MariaDB allows users to specify [microsecond precision](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/microseconds-in-mariadb/) on creating a table . And it would be good for OP to describe the use cases to see whether the `TIMESTAMP` data type can fit with application requirement , e.g. is the timestamp the only column in the p.k. or it is part of a composite key ? does the application require the precision ? ... etc

Comment: @Ham, I have little hope that the OP will clarify anything 6 years after the question was asked:-)